# Sierpiński space

Tags: general-topology, computer-science, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

Given a doubleton $X = \{0, 1\}$, the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) is the ordered pair $(X, S)$ where $S = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, X\}$ is a topology on $X$. The Sierpiński space is the smallest example of a topological space which is neither trivial nor discrete. The aim of this project is to study fundamental and topological properties of the Sierpiński space and its applications in mathematics and beyond....above is an abstract of a study I'm currently pursuing but stuck on applications of the Sierpiński space in computer science... I need some applications if you know any.

Comment: It is also the smallest space with a non-closed compact subset and is the smallest non-$T_1$ space and is the smallest non-trivial non-discrete space $Y$ such that any continuous $f:Y\to \Bbb R$ is constant.

Comment: [Synthetic Topology of Data Types and Classical Spaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.entcs.2004.09.017).

Comment: It is a concern that you have passed along your assigned project with little or no context to indicate you've thought about the problem.  I'll refrain for now from voting to close, but the goals of Math.SE to "collect and curate excellent content" are better served by including the details of your own search for "applications of the Sierpiński space in computer science".  This will help Readers avoid repeating information or approaches you've already explored, and put the importance of this Question to you personally in a better light.

Comment: Let $V \subset \mathbb P^n$ be a projective variety over $k$, and let $f \in k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ be a homogeneous polynomial. Then $f$ can be interpreted as a continuous function $f : V \to \Sigma$ taking values in the Sierpiński space $\Sigma = \{ \bot, \top \}$, and the preimage $f^{-1}(\bot)$ is a projective subvariety of $V$.

Answer (score 2):

It's a classic fact that if $X$ is $T_0$, then the set $\mathcal{F}$ of all continuous functions from $X$ to $S_2$, the Sierpiński space, separates points and points and closed sets, so by a classical embedding theorem $X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of the power $S_2^{\mathcal{F}}$ (in the product topology). So it's a "universal space" (or generating space) for all $T_0$ spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bijection between open sets of a topological space $X$ and the continuous maps from $X$ to $S$, where $S$ is the Sierpinski space (you can also state that in a more categorical way in case that you prefer that). Maybe that inspires you or is something that you like.

It arises as $\text{Spec}(R)$, when $R$ is a DVR. In case that you are interested in connections with algebraic geometry as well.

Maybe you are interested in sequences in $S$ As they have interesting convergence behaviour. Since you call the elements $0$ and $1$ you might have connections to some boolean stuff.

Comment: So it is a nice _topological_ target for characteristic functions.